# Verify for $a<b \in \mathbb R $ the interval $(a,b)$ is homeomorphic with $\mathbb R$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

[image: Question and answer for part 1]

Can someone explain to me where they are getting the numbers from for the first part $(a,b)$? How do you know to choose that formula and why does it work? I understand the concept of homeomorphisms, but I'm struggling to apply it when faced with a question.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that $\tan$ is a homeomorphism from an open finite interval to the whole real line. However, the interval happens to be $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ which is not the wanted $(a,b)$.

So, before applying $\tan$, we need to re-scale $(a,b)$ to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ with an homeomorphism. An affine function suffices: we let

$$ f(x) = \alpha x + \beta$$

and require $f(a) = -\pi/2$ and $f(b) = \pi/2$. Then we solve for $\alpha,\beta$, and put the solutions back into $f$.

---

A more direct way: first, we translate $(a,b)$ into $(0,b-a)$ by choosing

$$ 
\begin{array}{l}
f : (a,b) \to (0,b-a)\\
f(x) = x - a\\
\end{array}
$$

Then, we adjust the length of $(0,b-a)$ to mach that of $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, i.e., the length must be $\pi$. So, we divide by the old length and multiply for the new one.

$$ 
\begin{array}{l}
f : (a,b) \to (0,\pi)\\
f(x) = (x - a)\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{b-a}\\
\end{array}
$$

Then we translate it back so it starts from $-\pi/2$:
$$ 
\begin{array}{l}
f : (a,b) \to (-\pi/2,\pi/2)\\
f(x) = (x - a)\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{b-a} - \pi/2\\
\end{array}
$$

And this is the one in the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\tan: (-\pi/2, \pi/2) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism between $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. If we can show that the interval $(a, b)$ is homeomorphic to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, we are done.

So how do we transfer the first interval into the second one? Well first of all, it might be sensible to go from $(a, b)$ to $(0, b - a)$. This is done via the map $x \mapsto x - a$. From there, we can get to the interval $(0, 1)$ by using the map $x \mapsto x/(b - a)$. Our goal is to get an interval that has length $\pi$, so the next step could be to transform $(0, 1)$ to $(0, \pi)$ via $x \mapsto \pi x$. And the last step is to simply shift our new interval $\pi/2$ units to the left via $x \mapsto x - \pi/2$.

Combining these transformations all into one show that the map $x \mapsto \pi \frac{x - a}{b - a} - \frac{\pi}{2}$ is a homeomorphism from $(a, b)$ to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.